# Django: built in User with ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, database, orm

in my app I have built in User which is created during register.
After that, User can add URL to database. So User can have multiple URLs and vice versa.

in ***models.py*** I have

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Repository(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',on+delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    repositorys = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='users')
```

in my ***views.py***

```
url = request.session.get('url')
repo = Repository(url=url,user=request.user)
repo.save()
```

And my questions:

1) How can I check user's repos in shell? Should I import *django.contrib.auth.models.User*?

2) When Im looking at admin page and Repository table I can see that Repositorys column has 2 values: admin and user, despite of fact, that I added this url while being logged as admin, but value in user column is correct

Comment: Are your migrations updated?

Comment: @kamilyrb of course